# Using Sprites as an icons on a list of links

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a list of links with the ususal markup

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">a link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">a really long link that wraps
                over two or more lines
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">a link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">a link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I want to use a sprite to show icons to the left of the links and have the link text stay to the right:

```
ICON    some text that wraps and
        some more text that wraps
```

I'd like to do this without adding in more markup. and I have to support IE8 - so i think that means i can't use background-size

I have tried using a pseudo element - adding the background to the pseudo element.  this doesn't work because the actual content isn't in its own element - so there doesn't seem to be a way to make it not wrap under the icon.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to make this work in a good semantic way? Or do i have to add a span?

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: Do you want a different icon on each `<li>` or the same one?

Comment: My Css looks very much like Michaels - with the same problem  - when the text wraps, it comes under the icon - it doesn't stay left-aligned with itself / the first row of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this one:

```
li {
    margin-left: 25px; // |n| px must be equal to li a:before margin-left |n| px
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

li a:before {
    content: ' ';
    margin-left: -25px; // here ...
    width: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhSG6/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
​li a:before {
  content: '-';
  color: transparent;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5')
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhSG6/

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much what i'm doing - with the same problem  - the text doesn't align properly